# sudo asks for a password instead of getting it from stdin

Tags: zsh, sudo, macos-big-sur, iterm

I have a script running in an open terminal window:

```
while sleep 345600; \
  do pass="$(security find-generic-password -w -s 'service' -a 'account')"; \
     sudo --stdin <<< "${pass}" head /etc/hosts; \
done
```

When for a test I manually run this script having set `sleep` to 1, it works as intended, sudo getting the pass without user's interaction. When I then run the script with the 4 days delay, it does not run the same say in a specified time, sudo waiting for the password from a user's terminal (i.e. typed manually!). I can even set the `pass` variable to contain the actual plain-text password, of no avail.

Why this difference?

Comment: macOS sudo is very different from Linux sudo. It may not work under macos

Comment: A `--stdin` option does not exist - see [the macos sudo man-page](https://ss64.com/osx/sudo.html) - and actually according to the man page, only single-character options are allowed.  Perhaps this is the reason that  `--stdin` is not producing an error message, but simply taken as a normal argument to sudo.

Comment: @user1934428 , the system sudo man page (as of the year of 2020) shows that both short and long options are allowed.

Comment: If you look at the link I posted, it says on the bottom of the page 2022. It would be helpful if you could post a link to the man-page you are refering to.

Comment: @user1934428 , looks like the copyright is of the website itself, not of the actual man page. Here is a man page for the same sudo version as I have https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.9.5/sudo.man/ Anyway, if my sudo did not understand the long option, how could it have read the pass from the stdin at the first run?

Comment: The difference is probably due to sudo caching the credentials for 5 minutes after each successful run. Do `sudo -K` between runs to remove these for testing.

Comment: @jack : How did you verify that your sudo version you are linking here to, is the same you have installed on your computer? Did you do a `sudo --version` (respectively `sudo -V`) to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably safer to add the particular command you need to the sudoers config and allow it to be run without a password (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398656 for an example of this on macOS).

If that's not an option, you can try using the `--askpass` option: it takes the path to a command that will output the user's password on stdout when called. Put the `find-generic-password` command in a helper script and pass that to `--askpass`.